# Easiest IMAP archiver for multiple accounts

Tags: email, archive, imap, offlineimap

I'm pretty new to linux, Im running Ubuntu at the moment. On windows I was using a service called "mailstore" to archive the entire contents of multiple email accounts. I've seen a few searching google, but a lot of the "verbage" goes way over my head at the moment. All the accounts being archived use yahoo, and I dont need to be able to send mail.

Would be great to be able to add a full list of the accounts instead of manually adding them one by one. Also a plus if it has an integrated mail client for viewing emails as well, but thats not completely necessary. Would love any suggestions or links to any great guides for newbies to linux like me. Thanks!

Comment: Thunderbird can do this - but you have to configure each account separately. Have you considered modifying each account to redirect all new emails to a new (reliable) account? This works with Gmail accounts - don't know about Yahoo...